# Windows Server 2016 running McAfee ENS 10.5.1 causing 30 minute log on times

Tags: windows, login, mcafee

I have a server running Windows Server 2016 standard Version 1607 OS Build 14393.1358. The server is set up as a DNS Server and is being used for Active Directory Domain Services. We also have the File and Storage services role enabled. We have installed McAfee ENS 10.5.1 and when installed the server takes about 30 minutes to log on. It takes approximately 3 minutes to get to the log on page but once we log in the server takes 30 minutes to actually get to the desktop. We have disabled Windows Defender, and have also tried disabling On Access Scanning from the McAfee settings. If I am to remove McAfee the server only takes about 1 minute to log on, so I know that the issue is related to and being caused by McAfee.

If anyone has any idea on what might be causing the slow log on times then any support would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Edit - We have also updated to the latest Hotfixes supplied by McAfee support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We haven't upgraded to ENS yet. But, the first thing that comes to mind is that the HIPS / Firewall in ENS is blocking communication to localhost.

I found that it was impossible to get the older McAfee firewall to allow communications to localhost without setting up specific rules or disabling the firewall. It was quite silly really and a real limitation.

Try disabling any HIPS / Firewall included and see if that helps.

Comment: Okay, I will give that a try and let you know the results. Cheers

Comment: Totally agree, my first thoughts were about Firewall. Waiting for the feedback.